# How to get the keys from an object that seems to be matched dynamically. JAVA parcelable

Tags: java, android, arrays, parcelable

I am having issues resolving this object it seems to be made completely out of a string then dynamically being matched to its key.   if i try toString() this object it comes back with only the values(no keys) separated by a space.  this is a SignalStrength java class.  any help would be appreciated.  The reason I am looking for the keys is the on particular phones the indexes seem to be different. 
[image]

Comment: show the code that belongs to it

Comment: the object is recieved directly from this function https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength)

Comment: @jambuls add the info you provided in the question please, also explain a bit what you're trying to do and what's the problem. Right now the question is really hard to understand

Comment: can you not just use the getters for that class?

Comment: sadly it has only a few, but lots of values.  so i am forced to Stringify to and split the object to have access to it via array indexes in order to get a particular value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SignalStrength class ([source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/SignalStrength.java)) has about half its field getters annotated with @hide. This means they are not publicly accessible in the SDK with a get() like the other fields, hence android studio will not show those methods.

You have 2 options

1. Use `toString()` which provides values for all fields, and split it so you can access the values by index, like you are already doing.
2. Get the field values by reflection. Example

   ```
   Field field = null;
   try {
       field = SignalStrength.class.getDeclaredField("mLteRssnr");
       if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(int.class)) {
           field.setAccessible(true);
           int lteRssnr = (int) field.get(signalStrength); // pass the instance of SignalStrength here.

       }
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```